# Devise invitable batch invite - Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to user Devise invitable to add multiple users at once. Basically when someone creates an account, the first thing they'll want to do is add a bunch of users using the invitable form...

just not sure how to duplicate fields in the form and have them send a create request for each entry.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I presume you're using the devise_invitable gem. Does the user invite a batch of users just by using email addresses ?

Comment: Yup, you have both right. Using Devise_invitable, and you just enter the e-mail address, the user then gets an e-mail, and sets their password using the acceptance link sent to them.

Answer (score 16):

This is how I would do it.

> Provide a text area that accepts a comma-separated email list. Define
>   a new action that sends an invitation to each email in this list.

Lets assume a User model and a users controller for this example.

**Define a route for the batch_invite action.**

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    post 'batch_invite'
  end
end
```

**Define the batch_invite action in the users_controller**

```
def batch_invite
  #Validate the user_emails field isn't blank and emails are valid
  params[:user_emails].split(",").each do |email|
    User.invite!(:email => email)
  end
  #redirect_to appropriate path
end
```

**A form that accepts a comma-separated list of emails in a textarea.**

```
<%= form_tag batch_invite_users_path, :method => :post do %>
  <%= label_tag "Email ids of people you'd like to invite." %>
  <%= text_area_tag :user_emails %>
  <%= submit_tag "Invite!" %>
<% end %>
```

A couple of notes :

1. If you like your controller skinny, you could move the logic to the model, for instance, by creating a send_batch_invitations method in your User model and pass the params[:user_emails] as an argument to that method from the users controller.
2. Since the method that sends the invitations could take sufficient time to complete, I would suggest you assign this task to a background job processor, such as [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) or [resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque).
   There are [railscasts](http://railscasts.com) that demonstrate the usage of these two background job processors.